# can't access database without absolute path

Tags: c++, qt

i open my database like this and it works, but its obviously an absoulte path and it won't work anywhere else but my pc

```
mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
mydb.setDatabaseName("D:/QT/Matura/baza/lboards.db");
```

I can't access the database otherwise

```
if(mydb.open())
    qDebug() << "CONNECTED";
else
    qDebug() << "NOT CONNECTED";
```

this returns true if i set my path as

```
 mydb.setDatabaseName("lboards.db");
```

but the select statement that i run through the database returns nothing, but it does if i put the full path.

Comment: the path must be relative to the executable that is generated in the build and release folder.

Comment: what happens if you use D:\\QT\\Matura\\baza\\lboards.db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I wrote is like this, For your reference:

```
QString dbPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName( dbPath + "sqlite.db" );
if (!db.open())
{
    qDebug() << "do not find db file";
    return false;
}
```

And make sure `sqlite.db` in the same path of `yourapp.exe`

In my work space the path is : `...\qt_project\build-yourapp-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\`

Yours maybe not be the same, just adjust it a little.

Hope to be helpful.